# How to save $stmt results so I can loop through them later on?

Tags: php, mysqli

This part of my php code:

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($category, $number);
```

I know, I can walk through the resuls with:

```
while ($stmt->fetch())
```

But that is not what I want. I would like to have the results in a variable (array). Then use another loop from which I will walk through the database results many times.

It's important for me to search inside the result set with a loop.

Is there a command to put the fetch() result automatically inside an array? As you see, I have two columns, category and number.

Alternatively, I could query the database many times (for each category) but that is not what I prefer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You'll need to `fetch()` the results once - store them in an array and search that later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store each fetch operation in an array entry:

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($category, $number);

$results = [];

while ($stmt->fetch()) 
   $results[] = [$category, $number]
;
```

Then use that array as often as you like. However then I'd say that bound results are not really a good idea and I would use the resultsets `Traversable` nature to operate with the results instead of `::fetch()`.

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$cached = new CachingIterator($result, CachingIterator::FULL_CACHE);

foreach ($cached as $row) {
   ...
}

...

foreach ($cached as $row) {
   ...
}
```